# How to delete all files in folder python using Tkinter button and os

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to delete all files in a folder using os module in python this is what I have so far

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import random
from progress.bar import Bar
import os

backroundcolor = '#89CFF0'
#This is perfect no need to work on this
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('500x500')
        self.title('ProCleaner')
        self.configure(bg=backroundcolor)
        title = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to ProCleaner", font='Helvetica 18 bold', bg=backroundcolor)
        title.pack(pady= 2, padx= 2)
        deleteit = tk.Button(self, text ="Delete", command = self.delete)
        deleteit.pack(pady= 5, padx = 5)
#This is the problem
    def delete(self):
        dir = f'{os.getenv("USERPROFILE")}/AppData/Local/Temp'
        for f in os.listdir(dir):
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
#This also works
    def exit(self):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        exit()


app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you want to suggest any thing please do.

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes what is it, if not what is current behavior and desired behavior

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan\PycharmProjects\SpaceCleaner\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    app = Application()
  File "C:\Users\Juan\PycharmProjects\SpaceCleaner\main.py", line 17, in __init__
    deleteit = tk.Button(self, text ="Delete", command = self.delete())
  File "C:\Users\Juan\PycharmProjects\SpaceCleaner\main.py", line 23, in delete
    os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Juan/AppData/Local/Temp\\0508af8f-1127-4d78-

Comment: bf54-44a7a0916dde.tmp'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: First `command = self.delete()` should be `command = self.delete`.  Second the error obviously tells you that the file is being used by other process, so you cannot delete it.

Comment: I know but how can I get around it?

Comment: No you cannot basically because it is an OS level design.

Comment: ok thanks I will try something else